# Vim open multiple files starting with symbol '+'

Tags: matlab, vim, tabs

I have a folder called +Options, containing some matlab files:

> ```
> ▾ +Options/                    
>     AdaptativeFilterOpts.m     
>     EvtOpts.m                  
>     EvtRemoveNear.m            
>     EvtStepOpts.m              
>     FilterOpts.m               
>     MergeOpts.m                
>     MeterDataOpts.m
> ```

I want to open them on vim with -p option, like `vim -p +Options/*` but I get the following error:

> ```
> Error detected while processing command line:
> E492: Not an editor command: Options/AdaptativeFilterOpts.m
> E492: Not an editor command: Options/EvtOpts.m
> E492: Not an editor command: Options/EvtRemoveNear.m
> E492: Not an editor command: Options/EvtStepOpts.m
> E492: Not an editor command: Options/FilterOpts.m
> E492: Not an editor command: Options/MergeOpts.m
> E492: Not an editor command: Options/MeterDataOpts.m
> ```

How to expand the files so that vim can correctly open the files inside the +Options folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify a broader path.

```
vim -p ./+Options/*
```